# swift: slider thumb size

Tags: ios, swift

I have this slider:

[image]

I want to change size of native thumb like this:

[image]

Could I change thumb size in code and storyboard or I should use new thumb image?

Answer (score 1):

Just get a new thumb image.
To get a 24pt by 24pt thumb size, you should provide 48px by 48px, and 72x72 for @3x.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to use your new thumbImage with a slider that you code rather than one from a storyboard. You have to set the image to be used by both states (Normal and Highlighted) of the slider. Also, you can change the slider background by setting two images, the one before the slider as the mimimumTrackImage and the one after the slider as the maximumTrackImage.

Answer (score 0):

Add the assets the 3 sizes of images for the thumb, depending on the size you need, for example 16 for @1x, 32 for @2x, 48 for @3x and then from code assign the thumb to the slider

```
volumenSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "thumb_slider_3"), for: .normal)
volumenSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "thumb_slider_3"), for: .highlighted)
```